# ConcurrentModificationException when looping through lists from JPA in WebLogic

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic, concurrentmodification

When looping through a `List` that comes from a JPA query in WebLogic, the application throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` as soon as this list is traversed.

```
Caused By: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)
(rest of stack trace omitted)
```

The pseudo-code looks as follows:

```
final List<SomeEntity> someEntities = someEntityDao.getAllMatchingSomeCriteria();
for (final SomeEntity someEntity : someEntities ) {
    // ...
}
```

It's important to note that the list `someEntities` is **not** modified in any way, shape or form by the code. Rather, I've come to the conclusion that WebLogic is still filling up the list in a separate thread, while the main thread is already traversing it.

It can be solved as follows:

```
final List<SomeEntity> someEntities = new ArrayList<>(someEntityDao.getAllMatchingSomeCriteria());
for (final SomeEntity someEntity : someEntities ) {
    // ...
}
```

But that means having to go through all of the code, and that's a last resort. Is there a way to tell WebLogic to stop trying to be clever?

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace ?
WebLogic Server does not use a separate thread to fill up collections.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be possible to iterate over a collection that is simultaneously changing independent of the iterator.

Comment: But that would still involve changing any code that loops through a list.

Comment: @SeverityOne, True. Maybe give it a try annotating the related entities(relationship) as `FetchType.EAGER`. This will help in eager fetching related entries, but given that its a concurrent modification exception, i am not sure whether this will help. Please do update if you find a working solution.